# Unable to insert record through view

Tags: oracle

I have recently altered the base table to add two new columns in test environment and then due to some testing issue, rolled back to as it was before.

A view is already there for this table. When testing team try to insert through the view as they used to do before, they get ora-01733 virtual column not allowed here.

In fact, the view doesn't have any virtual columns, its only selecting the columns from the base table.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Thanks

I tried checking the view and there is no virtual column present.

Comment: Is there a virtual column in underlying **table**?

Comment: this view is created on top of another view which use cast, can this be a issue, however, it was working fine until l altered the table and again rolled back?
There is no virtual column in base table

Comment: So, table is in its previous state; right? Try to recreate both views (drop + create; not create or replace).

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me try and update, why not create or replace, interested to know the difference

Comment: Because *who knows* (I don't) what Oracle does in the background, in data dictionary. Maybe your previous actions affected the way views are stored so *replace* might not "clear" everything it should so I thought that starting from scratch (i.e. DROP first, CREATE next) might be a better option.